# Searching array key with reserved keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have created array as below

`["lists", { "getByTitle": "CardOperation" }, "items", { "filter": "Id eq 1" }, { "select": ["Title", "CustomerAge"] }];`

Now one key as **filter** I want find it to know it is exists in array but as it is reserved keyword i cannot search it

I tired

```
array.filter //not working

array["filter"] // not working
```

what should i do in this case, I am trying to find out if the array has an object with a key of filter at any index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

This loops through the array and returns true if an object with key "filter" exists, or otherwise, returns false.

```js
const myArray = ["lists", { "getByTitle": "CardOperation" }, "items", { "filter": "Id eq 1" }, { "select": ["Title", "CustomerAge"] }]

const hasObject = myArray.find(obj => typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && obj["filter"]) ? true : false;

console.log(hasObject);

const objectIndex = myArray.findIndex(obj => typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && obj["filter"]);

if(objectIndex == -1) {
    // there is no match in the array
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply regardless of position, can we find key

Comment: this wil not work as sometime filter key will be not their

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the array has an object with a key of filter at any index?

Comment: yes exactly, trying to find out if the array has an object with a key of filter at any index

Comment: Just updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: By default, the find function returns the element that it found, not a boolean. So the ternary returns true if there is an element and false if there isn't.

Comment: can we also find position of key

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240280/discussion-between-user81646-and-milind).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can filter on the word filter and it does not become reserved unless your result has a filter method

```js
const list = ["lists", { "getByTitle": "CardOperation" }, "items", { "filter": "Id eq 1" }, { "select": ["Title", "CustomerAge"] }];

const obj = list
  .filter(item => typeof item === "object" && 
                  Object.keys(item).includes("filter")); // loking for the key name "filter"

console.log(obj[0].filter); // using the key named filter
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the items in an array is to use their index.

---

```js
const array = ["arrays", { "getByTitle": "CardOperation" }, "items", { "filter": "Id eq 1" }, { "select": ["Title", "CustomerAge"] }];

console.log(array[3].filter);

/* Output: Id eq 1 */
```

---

I hope your problem is solved

Comment: I am trying to find out if the array has an object with a key of filter at any index

Answer (score -5):

You have to searcch array[3].filter

Comment: This wil not work as sometime filter key will be not their

Comment: This is scenario of constant array, Otherwise you have to make an array having dynamic objects